# WYSIWYG and TinyMCE stripping out float: left

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg, input-formats

I've got the WYSIWYG module installed and the TinyMCE javascript library as well. I've created a text format "Rich Text" which is similar to Filtered HTML but I've added more allowed tags.

I insert an image into my text and I set it to align left which adds `float: left` to the markup. However, when I save and view the page, the `float: left` has been stripped out.

I can't find any options in the WYSIWYG configuration or my "Rich Text" format that allows me to control this. Am I missing it somewhere?

Why is my `float: left` getting stripped out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

I downloaded a new module called [WYSWIWYG Filter](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter). On my Text Format, I turned off the `Limit allowed HTML tags` option and instead enabled the `WYSIWYG Filter` option. Then below in the WYSIWYG Filter settings, I configured the allowed HTML elements like so:

```
a[!href|target<_blank|title],
div[align<center?justify?left?right],
p[align<center?justify?left?right],
br,span,em,strong,cite,code,blockquote,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,
img[!src|alt|title|style|width|height|typeof],
@[style|title]
```

And I checked all the boxes to allow margins, padding, floating, etc.

Comment: This solution also works in Drupal 6

Comment: I'm currently using it on Drupal 7 and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some of this (if I remember correctly) from a given WYSIWYG profile preferences. You can add custom classes to apply to elements such as:

```
float left=float_left
```

then you make a CSS rule `.float_left: { float: left } ;`

You may find the [WYSIWYG_Filter](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter) module to be helpful in your needs.

Basically the WYSIWYG editor allows only certain things by default for safety. Drupal Input Formats further limit/allow what is allowed.

Comment: This is just a workaround and not the explanation of why it's happening or how to fix it. I need my users to be able to use the built-in methods of arranging their text in a WYSWYG fashion using the WYSIWYG editor. Teaching them and asking them to use a clunky work-around isn't going to work in this case.

Answer (score -1):

This does not help your exact question, but it is best to avoid WYSIWYG editors, it can often end up messing up the code or at least putting it in a way you cannot understand or draw sense from.

Comment: WYSIWYG works just fine and hyping your website is bad form.